# Almost equal probable sums with loaded dice

Tags: probability

It's known that it's impossible to assign probabilities to a pair of loaded dice so that the sums $2,...,12$ are equally probable. How would one set the probabilities $\{p_i: 1\le i\le 6\}$ and $\{q_i: 1\le i\le 6\}$ for the two dice so that $\sum_{i=1}^{11}\|s_i-1/11\|_2$ is minimal? ( for $1\le i\le 11$, $s_i$ is the probability that the sum is $i+1$).

Answer (score 1):

Let the dice be $A$ and $B$, and the probabilities of each numbered face be $\{a_i,b_i: 1\le i\le 6\}$.

Then the probability of each sum is:

$$\begin{matrix}
2&a_1b_1\\
3&a_1b_2+a_2b_2\\
4&a_1b_3+a_2b_2+a_3b_1\\
5&a_1b_4+a_2b_3+a_3b_2+a_4b_1\\
6&a_1b_5+a_2b_4+a_3b_3+a_4b_2+a_5b_1\\
7&a_1b_6+a_2b_5+a_3b_4+a_4b_3+a_5b_2+a_1b_6\\
8&a_2b_6+a_3b_5+a_4b_4+a_5b_3+a_6b_2\\
9&a_3b_6+a_4b_5+a_5b_4+a_6b_3\\
10&a_4b_6+a_5b_5+a_6b_4\\
11&a_5b_6+a_6b_5\\
12&a_6b_6\\
\end{matrix}$$

This is a linear programming problem to minimize the least squares error subject to the constraint that all probabilities must be positive. This is a numerical problem that lots of software can do, including the Solver add in of excel.

One solution is

> A             B
>
> 0.243883042   0.243883042
>
> 0.137478805   0.137478805
>
> 0.118637979   0.118637979
>
> 0.118638094   0.118638094
>
> 0.137479191   0.137479191
>
> 0.243882889   0.243882889

which has a least squares error of $.013$ and chances of:

> 2 0.059478938
>
> 3  0.067057498
>
> 4  0.076768004
>
> 5  0.090488054
>
> 6  0.113753104
>
> 7 0.184908719
>
> 8  0.11375296
>
> 9  0.090488084
>
> 10 0.07676813
>
> 11 0.067057644
>
> 12    0.059478863

Comment: With different starting values, Excel finds the following better solution. Die A probabilities (rounded) $(.50,0,0,0,0,.50)$, die B probabilities (rounded) $(.125,.1875,.1875,.1875,.1875,.125)$. The least squares error is $0.00284$, and the chances are $(0.625, .09375, .09374, .09376, .09375, .125, .09375, .09374, .09375, .093475, .0625)$.

Comment: Even better! Are there more ...

Comment: I tried a few other choices of initial value without finding anything else. Sometimes your solution appeared, and sometimes mine. The "GRG" engine I used guarantees a local minimum, and while Excel's Simplex LR method guarantees a global solution, I didn’t see how to set up the question to meet its requirements.

Comment: One can show by analytical computation that Dale's dice weights are algebraic, and can be written as rational linear combinations of algebraic numbers of degree $\leq 18$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.